# Creating JTextPane is leading to NullPointerException - OpenOffice Extension

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, awt, openoffice.org

I'm currently developing an Extension for OpenOffice. I'm using Java 1.6 and the OpenOffice SDK 4.1.2.

If I try to create a javax.swing.JTextPane, I get a NullpointerException in the Constructor of JTextPane.

```
public class Dialog extends javax.JFrame {

private final JTextPane jTextPane;
private final JTable jTable;



    public Dialog()  {
         jTable = new JTable();
         jTextPane = new JTextPane();

    }
}
```

The Dialog is initialized in another Thread:

```
public class DialogManager {
private static JournalDialog journalDialog;

public void showDialog() {




Thread startThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                     dialog = new Dialog();
                     ...
                }
            }
        }
 }
}}
```

The creation of JTable works fine, but in the next line I get a Nullpointerexception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Hashtable.put(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JEditorPane.registerEditorKitForContentType(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JEditorPane.registerEditorKitForContentType(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JEditorPane.loadDefaultKitsIfNecessary(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JEditorPane.getKitTypeRegistry(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JEditorPane.getEditorKitClassNameForContentType(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTextPane.<init>(Unknown Source)
at .gui.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:159)
at .gui.DialogManager$6$1.run(DialogManager.java:334)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I hope someone has an idea what causes this exception. I tried to run the extension in Java 1.7 and 1.8, but there is the same issue.

Best regards

Update 16.08.2016:
If I add a JTexPane over the Netbeans Palette into the Designer, it works. Only the initialisation in the constructor fails.

Comment: You know the NullPointerException drill: which line is `Dialog.java:159`?

Comment: its the line where "jTextPane = new JTextPane();" is called.

Comment: and 'DialogManager.java:334' is 'dialog = new Dialog();'

Comment: Consider trying to pare down your code to see if you can isolate the problem -- to see which parts of your code are essential for reproducing the problem.

Comment: Are you using any hash tables in your program? If so, are you putting any `Dialog` objects into them? The line `at java.util.Hashtable.put(Unknown Source)` of the trace concerns me.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try to isolate the problem. I'm not using a Hashtable, I think the call occur in a swing component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My dirty solution is to initialize the JTextPane twice within a try-catch. Because on the second call i don't get an exception.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be possible to use Swing for this task without crashing.  Instead, use the [com.sun.star.awt](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/awt/module-ix.html) module.  Complete examples are at http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/DevelopersGuide/examples.html#GraphicalUserInterfaces.

For more information, see [Creating Dialogs at Runtime](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Basic/Creating_Dialogs_at_Runtime).

One more link: [This example](http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/DevelopersGuide/ScriptingFramework/ScriptSelector/ScriptSelector/ScriptSelector.java) does use Swing.  Try it to see if the same problem occurs.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I edited my question, so hopefully it is clearer now.  It may have to do with a conflict between the way UNO handles events versus the way Swing handles them.  The standard recommendation is to use UNO instead of Swing for Java macro dialogs.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. Why I cannot use Swing for my GUI? In the wiki they don't say, that I have to use com.sun.star.awt My complete extension is written with swing, but only the JTextPane is making problems. https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/GUI/Graphical_User_Interfaces